# I want my service to run unelevated, but as a user who happens to be an Administrator (Windows / UAC)

Tags: java, windows, service, permissions, uac

Like the title says, I have written a program runs 'in the background', preferably as a Windows service.  (It happens to be written in Java, with the service part provided by the tanuki wrapper, if this matters.  Also, I'm running Vista, but am assuming that this happens on all versions of Windows with UAC.)  I run the service as 'User X'.

I also have a companion GUI program which is typically run from the start menu (unprivileged - i.e. 'asInvoker') - also as 'User X'.

The background program (aka the service) creates files.  My main need is for the unelevated GUI program to be able to read, write, and delete these files that are created by the service.

This works without hassle as long as 'User X' is not a member of the Administrators group.  (Of course an admin login is required to create the service, but that's okay.)

It also works if I turn off UAC, or if I run the background program not as a service (eg. from a command prompt).

But I just can't get it to work when 'User X' is a member of Administrators, and the background program is running as a service.

The symptoms of this problem are that process explorer shows my service process as running privileged (which I glean from the processes properties' Security tab showing 'BUILTIN\Administrators - Owner').  Also, all files created by the service are owned by 'Administrators'.

If I run my background program unprivileged from a command prompt, then process explorer shows 'BUILTIN\Administrators - Deny' and all files created by the program are owned by 'User X'.

Comment: Also - some notes on the things that I have tried so far - 'runas /trustlevel:0x2000' from within the service, embedded and external manifests on wrapper.exe and java.exe, 'icacls /setintegritylevel Medium', and modifying the security descriptor with 'sc.exe sdset' (though I admit I didn't get far with the security descriptors).  Some of these things succeeded in changing the service process's integrity level from 'High' to 'Medium', but none of them succeeded in
 changing the primary symptoms mentioned above.   So, needless to say - if anyone has any ideas on this, I would like to hear them.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question. I just looked up some information and cannot seem to find an answer for your question as asked initially, but I have a few alternative suggestions.

First, is it feasible to change your service app so that it creates the files required then it changes the permissions on them to what you want?

Second, does the service itself really have to run as "User X"? If so, why? Is there any way around that restriction? If you can bypass that requirement, then you can just make a normal user for the service to run as.

Third, you said preferably as a service, but not that this is a requirement. Does the environment this is used in allow you to use a scheduled task? The task scheduler itself runs as a system service, and it spawns other processes to do the work of the tasks you set up. And, when setting up a scheduled task, there is an option (a check box if you're using the GUI interface) to run the task with highest privileges or not. If you go this route, you can either have the task run at logon, or you can have it run at system start (in which case, make sure you do NOT have selected "run only if logged on"). This should otherwise be similar to your service setup.

Based on your comment below, I think the third suggestion might still be an option. You could still have status information similar to that of a service by making the program handle this in its own way. Your application could have a socket open for its cross-process communication. The background process could open a ServerSocket on a known port, and it could listen for status requests.

Your client application that your users are using could attempt to connect to this socket. If the socket connects, the process is running, otherwise it is not.

If you wanted only a "running/not running" status, this would be sufficient, and the ServerSocket could accept() a connection and then immediately shutdown and close the resulting Socket; you don't even have to accept or send any information since the initial connection is all you need.

If you want to keep the ability to startup/shutdown the task, you could use this same ServerSocket for that ability. If you aren't using the socket for any other data (only for the running-or-not mentioned above), you could have the background process terminate upon receiving any data at all on the socket, regardless of what it is, and the client (or whatever you use to shut down the background process) need only connect and send a byte instead of connect and immediately disconnect.

For startup, if you want to restrain the background process to one instance, there are a few ways to easily do that. I think you should be able to configure it via the task scheduler to only allow one instance of the task. Even if not, you could have a background process starting up connect to the given port it would otherwise listen on to see if it gets a connection from something else already there, if yes this is a second instance of it so abort. Or, even simpler yet, the creation of the ServerSocket should automatically fail if you are using a static port number, so just let the new ServerSocket(myPort) fail on its own, catch the exception, and abort. So there are three different ways to ensure that your process is acting like a proper service.

To start it up in the first place, you can tell the task scheduler to start it up on user logon, or on system boot as mentioned before. You can also configure the task so that users can initiate it themselves (if for whatever reason it's not already running), in fact, you could even have the client the user's are interacting with check on the status of the process and possibly start it automatically if it's not already started - try making a new process and exec() a command such as "schtasks /run /tn "Your Task Name""

I think that covers all the bases you mentioned, and then some. And all of the above should be pretty simple. If you do decide that this might be the route you'd like to take and if either I've overlooked something or you have other criteria which further restrict you from this, let us know again.

Comment: Re: the first - I think this would be quite difficult.  Part of this is due to the fact that my programs are written in Java, which lacks the fine-grained APIs required for this.  Also, many of the files that my background program creates are in created via third-party libraries and are very numerous (eg. a derby database), so even if I figured out the native API calls required to change the file ownership appropriately, I can't see how to write the code that would have to run around after all the other parts of my code and do that, in a reliable way.

Comment: Re: the second - no, it doesn't.  It will be easier for my users, though.  They are typically not sysadmins.  Also, I am vague as to the circumstances under which my service (run as a normal user) will write files that are globally readable (or at least, readable by User X when written by 'User S (for service)'.)  I would rather avoid this complication.

Comment: That checkbox ('run with highest privileges') sounds like it would save me but I don't see how, with a task, to get the start / stop / and 'am I running?' functionality of services.

Comment: I see. Valid points for all. The best response I can come up with for that is regarding my third suggestion. Your application could handle that itself. I will edit my answer to reflect that.

Comment: I appreciate all the thought that went into your proposed work-around with tasks, but I'm afraid that it is too complicated to be useful to me.  I am going to hold out hope that there is a checkbox or similar somewhere out there.

Answer (score 1):

In the end I implemented a work-around using Windows scheduled tasks, similar to what is described above, but instead of implementing my own 'start/stop' interface, I wrote a Windows service that manages my program, run as a task.  When the service starts, it starts a task, and when the service is asked to stop, is stops the task.  So instead of using a socket for the parent to query if the child is running, I use schtasks /Query and parse the output.  To make the task exit if the parent exits, I used an RMI keepalive method on my app that was already there.

Windows scheduled tasks have some undesirable defaults for a service that are modifiable through the task scheduler GUI, but not through schtasks' command-line options - namely ExecutionTimeLimit, DisallowStartIfOnBatteries, StopIfGoingOnBatteries.)  But these options can be queried and modified using the '/XML' option to schtasks /Query and /Create.  So that's what I did.

I also needed to detect if I'm running on a newer or older version of Windows, because if it's an older version (without UAC) then this will all be unnecessary but more importantly defining the task will not work without supplying a password, because the /NP option to schtasks is not available.

The only weakness (other than being complicated) that I know of with my implementation is due to schtasks' note on the /NP option - "Only local resources are available."  This turns out to mean that mapped network drives won't be accessible (and I hope that's all it means.)  I have SMB support implemented independently, in Java, in my app where it is needed, so this weakness wasn't the end of the world.

This was a lot of work for what can probably be done with a single Win32 call.  Maybe one day I will figure out how to do that.

Comment: It is possible to this from the Win32 API, but it isn't entirely straightforward.  You would need to create a restricted token using CreateRestrictedToken and use CreateProcessWithTokenW to launch the child.  The child should also be put into a job, to make sure it can't be left running after the service has stopped.  It isn't a huge amount of work, but it can be a bit tricky to get all the details right.  I'm not sure either option is terribly reliable in terms of security, it would be preferable to use a non-admin user or a service account.